# How to add post (blogger) using Google API v3

Tags: php, google-api, blogger

i want to add new post in blogger using google API v3. I was created API Key in console.google.com and using this code:

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blogid.'/posts/';
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'blogger#post',
    'blog' => array('id' => $blogid),
    'title' => 'This is title',
    'content' => 'With <b>exciting</b> content...'
);
$head = array();
$head[] = 'Authorization: '.$token;
$head[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$page = curl($url, json_encode($postData), '', $head);
var_dump($page);
```

$token is a API key, but respose error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Everybody, can you help me. Thanks so much !

Comment: As the response says: your credentials (`$token`) are invalid.

Comment: I was try API key and Secret Key (OAuth 2.0). They are invalid

Comment: You probably need `'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token` as specified under [standard query parameters](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#st_params) and keep in mind that tokens expire after an hour so you might need a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Token shouldn't be an API key but the access token.

You can generate your access token here - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Better make a request using Step 3 at the playground itself to check the request headers and body and make sure that your sending the Post request in the same manner.

( Make sure to add Bearer before the Token as you would see in the request made through Oauth 2 Playground)